# Rails 4, order in has_many :through. It simply does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have this situation:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :movies, through: :tickets
end


class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :students, through: :tickets
end


class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie, counter_cache: true
    belongs_to :student
end


class Cinema < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :movies, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :students, through: :movies
end
```

I have this code in my (**movie_controller.rb**) controller:

```
def show
  @tickets = @movie.tickets.includes(:student)
end
```

Now in my grid (**show.html.erb**) I have this situation:

```
<% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= ticket.student.id %></td>
    <td><%= ticket.student.code %></td>
    <td><%= ticket.student.last_name %> <%= ticket.student.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= ticket.hours %></td>
    <td><% if ticket.payed %>Yes<% else %>No<% end %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Now I want to order the students by their "last_name, first_name", but if I use this code in my controller:

```
@tickets = @movie.tickets.includes(:student).order('students.last_name')
```

in my console I have a SQL query like this:

`"AS t0_r0 .... AS t0_r1 ..."` and so on... **is it normal?**

Is my logic wrong?

If I use in my model a code like this:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :students, -> { order('last_name, first_name') }, through: :tickets
end
```

**nothing works**. My list is ordered not by last name and first name, but default (id).

How to do better?

**UPDATE**:

I changed from model "Children" to "Student".

Comment: the `Children` class should be `Child` e.g. `'child'.pluralize #=> 'children'; 'children'.pluralize #=> 'children'; 'children'.singularize #=> 'child'`. Rails infers things like class name and table name from the association name (using methods like pluralize and singularize) so if you must use children as a class name then you will need to tell the associations e.g. `has_many :childrens, class_name: 'Children'`...` not sure what your tables look like but you may need to add `primary` and `foreign` keys as well.

Comment: Can you try to use `reorder('childrens.last_name ASC')` instead of your current `.order()` ? ; `"AS t0_r0 .... AS t0_r1 ..."` is Rails' generated names for table joins (`t0_r0` is an alias for table 0 row 0). It is perfectly normal to have this generated in your SQL queries using `joins`/`includes`

Comment: @engineersmnky, I edited the question with Children >> Student.

Answer (score 0):

""AS t0_r0 .... AS t0_r1 ..." and so on... is it normal?"

Yes, the includes has been implemented as an outer join, so the order by can be applied to the rows returned from the tickets table.

To use scope for this, you'd want to do *something like*:

```
student.rb

def self.by_last_name
  order(:last_name)
end

ticket.rb

def self.by_student_last_name
  joins(:student).merge(Student.by_last_name)
end
```

... then ...

```
@tickets = @movie.tickets.by_student_last_name
```

Comment: Yes but I don't like this query. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @JohnSam what do you mean you *"dont like this query"*? You certainly can create an alternative with raw sql by hand but why?

Comment: Sorry. I mean: is that query good in terms of performances? When, for example, tickets and childrens are hundreds? Is right my logic of using that code in the controller? Is The right way of using queries in ActiveRecord for that type of relations?

Comment: 1) Yes, this is the optimum query. 2) Even more so, even if it's in the millions. 3) You might make it a scope in a model instead. 4) Yes, ActiveRecord has made the correct choice here.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, thanks for your answers. How you suggest to create a scope in the model?

Comment: Nothing against this answer; really more complaining about rails. The whole point is to be composable, but rails often aliases columns without my consent, making it difficult to justify using...